# Converting a get-by-index function into an iterator for use with STL algorithms

Tags: c++, iterator, template-meta-programming, c++17

This is a solution to [Advent of Code 2016, Day 8](http://adventofcode.com/2016/day/8). The tricky part of this problem is that you have to be able to rotate both the *rows* and *columns* of a two-dimensional array. Rotating a *row* is easy using `std::rotate`, but rotating a *column* seems much harder.

My basic approach was to write a "getter function" such that `get(i)` returns the `i`th element of the (row/column) currently being rotated; and then I wrote a very straightforward "rotate by 1 in a loop" function in terms of `get(i)`. That implementation is marked `// DUMB` below. (Although, given this particular problem's range of input, "it's not dumb if it works.")

But I'd really like to use `std::rotate` if possible, both for speed ("rotate by 1 in a loop" is O(`by`x`n`), when it should be just O(`n`)) and for elegance. So I wrote a wrapper that takes the "getter" function and turns it into an iterator. This is marked `// CLEVER` below.

- Does the STL or Boost already provide some way to turn an indexed "getter" function into a random-access iterator?
- I turn my array into a "getter" function and then turn the getter function into an iterator; seems a bit roundabout. Does the STL or Boost already provide a straightforward way to construct a "strided" iterator on an array?
- I see that `std::iterator` is deprecated in C++17. In C++17, would my code Just Work if I stopped inheriting from `std::iterator`? or what's the best practice for writing iterators these days?

---

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

const int HEIGHT = 6;
const int WIDTH = 50;
bool grid[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

#if 1
template<typename Getter>
auto make_iterator(const Getter& get, int i)    // CLEVER
{
    using T = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(get(i))>;
    struct It : std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T> {
        const Getter *get_;
        int i_;
        It(const Getter& g, int i) : get_(&g), i_(i) {}
        It& operator++() { ++i_; return *this; }
        It operator++(int) { It temp = *this; ++i_; return temp; }
        decltype(auto) operator*() const { return (*get_)(i_); }
        bool operator==(const It& rhs) const { return i_ == rhs.i_; }
        bool operator!=(const It& rhs) const { return i_ != rhs.i_; }
    };
    return It(get, i);
}

template<typename Getter>
void rotate_right(int by, int n, const Getter& get)
{
    std::rotate(make_iterator(get, 0), make_iterator(get, (n - by) % n), make_iterator(get, n));
}
#else
template<typename Getter>
void rotate_right(int by, int n, const Getter& get)
{
    while (by != 0) {             // DUMB
        bool temp = get(n-1);
        for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; --i) {
            get(i+1) = get(i);
        }
        get(0) = temp;
        --by;
    }
}
#endif

void process_input(std::string line)
{
    std::smatch m;
    if (std::regex_match(line, m, std::regex("rect (.*)x(.*)"))) {
        int a_wide = std::stoi(m.str(1));
        int b_tall = std::stoi(m.str(2));
        for (int i=0; i < a_wide; ++i) {
            for (int j=0; j < b_tall; ++j) {
                grid[j][i] = true;
            }
        }
    } else if (std::regex_match(line, m, std::regex("rotate row y=(.*) by (.*)"))) {
        int row = std::stoi(m.str(1));
        int by = std::stoi(m.str(2)) % WIDTH;
        rotate_right(by, WIDTH, [&](int i) -> decltype(auto) { return grid[row][i]; });
    } else if (std::regex_match(line, m, std::regex("rotate column x=(.*) by (.*)"))) {
        int column = std::stoi(m.str(1));
        int by = std::stoi(m.str(2)) % HEIGHT;
        rotate_right(by, HEIGHT, [&](int i) -> decltype(auto) { return grid[i][column]; });
    } else {
        assert(false);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string buf;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, buf)) {
        process_input(buf);
    }
    for (int i=0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
            printf("%c", grid[i][j] ? '#' : '.');
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the input to create iterator only matrix? If yes, then you could make (non portable) assumption that they are laid out in memory row wise and always jump at constant distance.

Comment: @Incomputable: Yes, that assumption would be reasonable in my case; that's what I was getting at with the phrase "strided iterator". But does such a thing exist? and/or can it be implemented in less code than what I've got here?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the boost. I believe it will have the same code size, but it is certainly possible to remove that getter step.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a vector<bool> or the c++11 array class?  Then you've got iterators and indexes that you can use

Comment: @tinstaafl: As of C++14, the core language provides built-in arrays that are about as full-featured as the library ones. ;) E.g. `std::begin(a)` and `std::size(a)` work for core language arrays `T[N]` just the same as they do for `std::array<T,N>`. Anyway, I'm not sure what specific change you're proposing: is it just to change the one line `bool grid[HEIGHT][WIDTH];` to `std::array<std::array<bool, WIDTH>, HEIGHT> grid;` and leave the rest untouched?